# Chrome omnibox returning blank boxes

Tags: google-chrome, omnibox

My Google Chrome has started returning big empty boxes recently for the omnibox auto-suggestions.

I have:

- Rebooted
- Checked Chrome is up to date
- Tried an assortment of Google searches
- Disabled all extensions

And nothing. How can I diagnose this? Is there a configuration setting for the text colour, perhaps?!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK, as usual, the moment you ask you "solve".

The problem lies in the Touch UI mode.

Under chrome://flags/ disable `Touch Optimised UI` and it's "fixed". Well, it's a workaround until they fix the `Touch Optimised UI` bug, at least :)

Others with the same problem (and where I got the answer):
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Fdt2SLpuZxE